# How can we add login extra field FOSUserBundle in Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, entity, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.2

How can we add login extra field FOSUserBundle in Symfony 3. I have attached screenshot also my FOSUserBundle on that I want to add First Name and Last Name, I have read all documentation regarding this but unable to understand.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ihTW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the desired fields in the Entity User Class and then override the Form Registration to add them in the builder and show into the view accordingly. I suggest to follow [this tutorial](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/fosuserbundle).